# Dialog box content empty upon either Jquery Post or Form Submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom

I have a view which renders a partial view and in this view there is a dialog box which contains a list of check boxes. This view is called Create.

The process flow of this page is:

1)The first time users opens this page, they upload a file by selecting the file and by hitting the upload button. The action method parses the file and returns the model and displays a set of dates in the dialog box in the form of a check box list.

2) From this dialog box they select/check dates and using the select button in the dialog box, A post request is made to a controller action which based on the selected checboxes calculates a few form fields and returns the partial view.

3)Once users are okay with the pre-populated fields returned  they click save and record is saved.

Everything works fine on the Create page. In the edit page it seems to be a different story. When the page is loaded the first time, the list which was saved upon create, is present in the dialog box. However when they hit Select within the dialog box, the post to the action method receives this list as empty.  I am not sure why it is null. Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong but the code for edit is as follows.

Thanks!!

**THE JS FILE:**

var RunDialog;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

    RunDialog = $("#runDatestreeview").dialog({ closeOnEscape: true, stack: false, autoOpen: false,
        modal: false, resizable: true, draggable: true, title: 'Select Run Dates to Auto-Populate Form Fields:',
        width: 600, height: 500, position: 'center',
        buttons: { Select: function () {
            $.post("/RunLogEntry/LogFileConfirmation",
              $("#form").serialize(),
               function (data) {
                   $("#runDatestreeview").remove();
                   $("#testExceptiontreeview").remove();
                   $("#main").html(data);
                   $(RunDialog).dialog("close");
               }, "html");
        },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    RunDialog.closest("div.ui-dialog").appendTo("#form");


    $('#RunDatesChildDialogLink').click(function () {
        $(RunDialog).dialog("open");
    });


    //Region Auto-Open Modal Box
    var modalOpen = $("#LogModals").val();

    if (modalOpen == "0") {
        $("#runDatestreeview").dialog({ autoOpen: true });
    }
    //End Auto Open Modab Box Regiom


});
```

**EDIT VIEW**

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runLogEntry.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var runlogListErrorsUrl = '@Url.Action("ListErrorCodes", "RunLogEntry")';
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <div id="main">
        @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialViewEdit", Model)
    </div>

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Partial View for Edit** I am not posting the entire model for the sake of readability. The Dialog div is called `runDAtestreeview`.

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runDates.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/testexception.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.RunDatesDisplay != null && Model.RunDatesDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Run Dates")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="RunDatesChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to Select/View Run Dates</span>
            <br />
            <span id="RunDatesDisplayy" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">
            </span></span>
    }
</div>

<div id="runDatestreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 400px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <table class="grid" style="width: 600px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Run Dates:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Minimum Replicate:
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RunDatesDisplay)
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to trivial but changing the form to the following by including "id = form" made it work. Looks like Earlier when I was clicking the select button, the form was null.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
```